# Is it possible to create a Facebook page using their API?

Tags: facebook

Our client is wanting to have their application actually create new pages on behalf of a user. I've found a couple of workarounds for posting items to pages that already exist, but nothing for creating new pages (although the documentation on Facebook pages is pretty sparse). Any suggestions?

Comment: Did u ever find out how to do this, Sean? Have a similar project.

Answer (score 1):

your APP need Standard Access permission from Facebook. Once you have this permission you can performance this action using /{user_id}/accounts, to create a new page under this user. This is my way to create new pages, and It works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you will need to first get [Standard access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access) to the Facebook Marketing API.